# BigQuery if statement not return null for wrong case

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a question for using if statement. When I using if statement without null for else statement I take result but I don't want it. When I take null in else I take result null.

For example

```
 if(h1 is not null, CONCAT(cast(h1 as STRING),':', h1_desc), 'NULL')
```

this is correct result but if I take non string value of null for example

```
 if(h1 is not null, CONCAT(cast(h1 as STRING),':', h1_desc), NULL)
```

this result is return null but this is wrong.

Also I use case when statement but result is same. When I use string or something this result is correct but when I use null result is not correct.

I can't use IFNULL because of statement is important for this query.

So that I need a help.

Is BigQuery if statement not support null?

Comment: CASE WHEN h1 IS NULL THEN NULL ELSE CONCAT(cast(h1 as STRING),':', h1_desc) END

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work:

```
 if(h1 is not null, CONCAT(cast(h1 as STRING),':', h1_desc), cast(NULL as string))
```

Edit: I was wrong, this shouldn't even be necessary

Comment: No it is not working :( I think this is bug. Because of Hive is supported by null values in if statement for result. I don't know

Comment: It is hard to figure out without knowing what values h1 can actually take, especially when 'null', if it's an empty string, or else